# How to change link location in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My Word document has links to Excel that, when displayed, look like this:

{ LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 "C:\\Users\\Shawn\\projects\\Workbook1.xlsm" "Range1" }

I need my macro to be able to change this to a new path/file:

```
strNewFile = "C:\Users\Shawn\OtherFolder\Workbook2.xlsm".
```

(Note the single backslashes vs. the double ones.)

What's the simplest way? (Using Word 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post seemed to have the answer: 
[Linked Table in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716107/linked-table-in-ms-word/19735211#19735211)

Using this code:

```
Dim fieldCount As Integer, x As Long
With ActiveDocument
  fieldCount = .Fields.Count
  For x = 1 To fieldCount
    With .Fields(x)
      If .Type = 56 Then
        'only update Excel links. Type 56 is an excel link
        Debug.Print .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newfile '
        .Update
        .LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
        DoEvents
      End If
    End With
  Next x
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub changeSource()

Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog  'FileDialog object
Dim thisField As Field
Dim selectedFile As Variant    'must be Variant to contain filepath of selected item
Dim newFile As Variant
Dim fieldCount As Integer



'create FileDialog object as File Picker dialog box
Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)



With dlgSelectFile
'use Show method to display File Picker dialog box and return user's action
    If .Show = -1 Then

        'step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection
        For Each selectedFile In .SelectedItems
            newFile = selectedFile    'gets new filepath
        Next selectedFile
    Else   'user clicked cancel
    End If
End With
Set dlgSelectFile = Nothing



'update fields
fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
For x = 1 To fieldCount
    ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
Next x

End Sub
```